# Custom View. Создание собственного View

Tags: java, android, view

Отдельно прописан класс `MyView`:

```
public class MyView extends View {
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
}
}
```

и добавлен в `layout`:

```
 <MyView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:id="@+id/view"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

В результате запуска вылетает exception:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class MyView

Помогите решить проблему, и объясните в чем моя ошибка.

Comment: путь до MyView в разметке должен быть полным , с именем пакета: `<com.example.MyView>` . [Гайд](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как сказал @pavlofff  "путь до MyView в разметке должен быть полным , с именем пакета: `<com.example.MyView>` ."

[Гайд](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)